# Search Q&A is much less efficient than the engine behind the search while you type a question

Tags: feature-request, support, search, search-engine

I noticed that the search engine that brings up possible duplicate questions while you're typing a question works great.  Is there a way to use the same search engine in the 'Search Q&A' search box?

Comment: I'm not sure if multiple feature requests are recorded or not but if there's a duplicate for a 'feature-request' perhaps the feature should get more attention.  I hope the duplication of the 'feature-request' doesn't go to waste.